# php array keys array values insert

Tags: php, insert

Update:

Index page is performs the action of the function, 
Below is my current code, above this i have a fetch all which works well, but this insert isnt  working as it doesn't insert into the database, is it because i need an update all after it before i can test insert?

```
   <?php
 function insert(array $values, $tablename)  
 {

        $key = "";
        $val = "";

foreach($values as $keys=>$record){


     if($keys == ""){
       $key .= $keys;
     } 
     else{
       $key .= ','.$keys;
     }


   if($val == ""){
       $val .= $record;
       insert into $tablename($keys)values($val);


     } 
     else{
       $val .= ','.$record;
       insert into $tablename($keys)values($val);

     }
  }
 } 


?>
```

Comment: `$values` !== `$vaules`.... and will just give the word `Array` anyway, when used like this

Comment: `$pr1` isn't in scope

Comment: Bad concatenation (or lack of concatenation, or not escaping quotes inside a quoted string

Comment: And probably a whopping great SQL injection vulnerability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have few mistakes

```
function insert(array $values, $tablename)
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename ("$vaules". implode(",", array_keys($pr1)) .") VALUES ('$vaules$, ". implode(",", array_values($pr1)) ")";
```

Maybe you want something like this

```
function insert(array $values, $tablename){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (".implode(",", array_keys($values)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($values))."')";
}
```

You are using some $pr1 value that do not exist in function. But also I woul like that you will do something with this query in this function.

Comment: Thanks this works very well, do you mind explaining to me whats going on to help me learn?

Answer (score 0):

let me to be specific.
for example you have a table employee with emp_id, emp_first_name,emp_last_name and email_id fields.
and you have array for values like this

```
$values = array(
        emp_first_name  => John,
        emp_last_name => Malick,
        email_id => john@gmail.com

    )
```

now call insert function from index page using below code
first of all include file in which you placed a insert function.
for example in File1.php you placed a insert function then

```
include 'File1.php';
$result =  insert('employee',$values);
```

now in insert function,

```
 function insert($tablename,$values){

        foreach($values as $keys=>$record){

            $key_array[] = $keys;
            $myvalue = $record;
                if($record == ''){
                    $value_array[] = "'NULL'";
                }else{
                    $value_array[] = "'".$myvalue."'";
                }


          }


    $keys = implode(",", $key_array);
    $values = implode(",", $value_array);   
    insert into $tablename($keys)values($val);

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help thanks very much, i will give that a go

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work, it launched the first select all and then when i try to insert i don't get any results back, i think its because i am not sure where this goes 'insert into tablename($keys)values($val);'   I have updated my code now

Comment: Thanks sorry though i am very new to this, where abouts do you put this after else and before the } ?  for each statement?

Comment: @Lewis- write like this in if $val .=  ' $record ' ; and in else part $val .= '  ,  "  '   .$record. '  "  ' ;

Comment: Thanks @RubbySmith Sorry i am so new to Php and am still confused thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: @Lewis- please tell me where you are confused i will try my best to solve your confusion?

Comment: Hi I am just confused on the way to structure it out, to make it work, and to do with the insert into tablename($keys)values($val); I have the index page set up to call the function fine its just the other page which uses the insert all function which i am struggling with.

Comment: Hi @RubbySmith i am still stuggling for my index i have the code, i have added that to the top, and your fucntion currently isn't working thanks.